# Prove: $x$ is an adherent point of $E \subset X$ if every open neighborhood of $x$ has a non-empty intersection with $E$

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, self-learning

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $E \subset X$.

> Prove: $x$ is an adherent point of $E$ if every open neighborhood of $x$ has a non-empty intersection with $E$.

What I have so far:

Define the open ball $B(x,\epsilon) := \{ y: d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$

If $x \in E$, we are done (as every point in $E$ is an adherent point of $E$). So assume $x \notin E$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $y \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap E$.

Since $B(x,\epsilon)$ is open, and $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$, there exists $\epsilon_1 > 0$ such that $B(y,\epsilon_1) \in B(x,\epsilon)$.

At this point, if we can establish that some points in $B(y, \epsilon_1)$ are also in $E$, we can say there is a sequence of points $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset E$ that is within $\epsilon$ of $x$, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $E$, and hence is an adherent point. But how can we say that there are points in $B(y,\epsilon_1)$ that are also in $E$?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of the adherence ? To me, $x\in \overline{E}$ if $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap E\neq\emptyset$. But you probably have an other definiton since it's what you want to prove.

Comment: A point $x$ is an adherent point of a set $E \subset X$ if it is the limit of some sequence in E.  (from https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/254a-notes-8-a-quick-review-of-point-set-topology/)

Comment: So I'm trying to show that if $x \notin E$, then $x$ must be a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the open balls of radius $1/n$ centered at $x$. For all $n$ by hypothesis we know that exists $x_n \in E \cap B_{1/n}(x)$. Then the sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset E$ converges to $x$.

EDIT: I corrected the proof.

Comment: We do not know that $x$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset E$. We want to prove that from the fact that $B(x,\epsilon) \cap E \neq \phi$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my mistake! I corrected the proof.